# NSDateFormatter results different from apple.cn screenshots

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsdateformatter

The iPhones at http://apple.com/iphone have `9:41 AM` in the status bar for [esoteric reasons](http://www.tuaw.com/2014/04/14/why-9-41-am-is-the-always-the-time-displayed-on-iphones-and-ipad/). I'm trying to make localized screenshots for my app, so I consulted http://apple.com/cn/iphone, where they use `上午9:41` consistently. However, when I set my locale to `zh-Hans` or `zh-Hant` using the `-AppleLanguages` flag, `NSDateFormatter` spits out `9:41 上午`. Here is the code I’m using:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *originalLocale = dateFormatter.locale;
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"9:41 AM"];
dateFormatter.locale = originalLocale;

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

This code produces the correct format in `en_US`, but the wrong one in `zh-Hant`. Is there a way to get a localized version of `@"h:mm a"`, other than hardcoding it for each language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the `dateFormat`, set the `timeStyle` to access the appropriate built-in format. `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` looks right to me. There's also `dateStyle` should you want it.

So, sample code:

```
NSDateFormatter *newformatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
newformatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh-Hant"]; 
newformatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSLog(@"%@", [newformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Output:

```
上午12:10:40
```

Comment: `NSDateFormatterShortStyle` did it for me, `timeStyle` is the piece I was missing. Thanks!